# Yule walker equation limited matrix size

Tags: discrete-signals, moving-average, autoregressive-model

**Definitions**

For an ARMA model

$$x_n=-\sum_{p=1}^P a_px_{n-p}+\sum_{q=0}^Qb_qw_{n-q}$$

where $w_n$ is zero mean stationary white noise with unit variance.

It is straightforward to show that the autocorrelation of $x_n$, $R_{XX}[r]$ is given by:

$$R_{XX}[r]=-\sum_{p=1}^P a_pR_{XX}[r-p]+c_r$$

where

$$c_r = \begin{cases}\sum_{q=r}^Qb_qh_{q-r} & r\leq Q \\ 0 & r>Q \end{cases}$$

where $h_n$ is the impulse response of the system, i.e. $x_n=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}h_mw_{n-m}=h_n*w_n$

**Question**

I have seen in textbooks that the equation for $R_{XX}[r]$ expands to

$$R_{XX}[0]+\sum_{p=1}^Pa_pR_{XX}[-p]=c_0$$
$$R_{XX}[1]+\sum_{p=1}^Pa_pR_{XX}[1-p]=c_1$$
$$\vdots$$
$$R_{XX}[Q]+\sum_{p=1}^Pa_pR_{XX}[Q-p]=c_Q$$
$$R_{XX}[Q+1]+\sum_{p=1}^Pa_pR_{XX}[Q+1-p]=c_{Q+1}=0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$R_{XX}[Q+P]+\sum_{p=1}^Pa_pR_{XX}[Q+P-p]=0$$

These can then easily be put into the classic matrix form $\mathbf{R}_X'\mathbf{a}'=\mathbf{c}'$.

This makes perfect sense except for one detail - **why do the textbooks stop the equations at $R_{XX}[Q+P]$? Why do they not continue to $R_{XX}[Q+P+1]$ etc.?**

I have tried fruitlessly to show that $\sum_{p=1}^Pa_pR_{XX}[Q+P+1-p]=0$ meaning $R_{XX}[Q+P+1]=0$ so that there isn't any point in considering these equations.

I also tried to show from $x_n=-\sum_{p=1}^P a_px_{n-p}+\sum_{q=0}^Qb_qw_{n-q}$ that $R_{XX}[Q+P+1]=0$. I would really appreciate it if someone helped me out here, I'm sure the answer is simple and obvious but I just can't see it.